# Probability (removing balls)

Tags: probability

I am starting learning probability and am struggling with a few questions. Can someone please explain the approach to get this question, thanks.

**A bucket contains 15 balls. 4 of the balls are blue. 3 balls are removed from the bucket. What is the probability that 2 of these (removed) balls are blue?**

I know to assume the balls are removed one after the other and once a ball is taken out it is not put back in. Thanks

Comment: Request for clarification:  is the desired event that **at least** two of the balls are blue, or **exactly** two of the balls are blue?

Comment: Hi, sorry it should read "**exactly** 2 of the balls are blue". thanks

Comment: To be accurate, you have to state whether or not each ball has an equal chance of being drawn and if not, what the individual probabilities of each ball (or class of balls) are.

Answer (score 1):

If we need exactly two blue balls out of three, that means our outcomes of interest are the ordered triplets $$(b,b,n), (b,n,b), (n,b,b),$$ where $b$ is the event of getting a blue ball, and $n$ is the event that the ball is not blue.

So let's take a look at the probability of observing the first of these three desired outcomes.

When the first ball is removed, the probability it is blue is $p_1 = 4/15$.  Now given that the first ball removed is blue, the probability the second is also blue is $p_2 = 3/14$.  Finally, given that the first two balls removed were blue, the probability the last ball is **not** blue (because we need exactly two blue balls) is $p_3 = 11/13$.  So the probability of observing the first outcome is $$\frac{4}{15} \cdot \frac{3}{14} \cdot \frac{11}{13}.$$  Can you calculate the rest?

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I did. I then said that there is 3C1 ways of picking them out, so multiplied the answer to the product you have there (22/105) by 3 and said that there is a 22/35 probability of getting two blues. Is this correct. Thanks again.

Comment: ^^ sorry a math slip by me in the above comment. The product of the above terms should say 22/405. So the total probability if multiplying by 3 is correct is 66/455. Is this ok?

Answer (score 0):

What approaches did you try? I would recommend first drawing  tree of outcomes.  Then you can use conditional probabilities.  Does it help?

Comment: I found the probability that the first ball is blue to be (4/15) and multiplied it by the 2nd ball being blue (3/15) and final ball not being blue (11/13). Then I got confused how to make it for other cases,so just thought that there is 3C1 ways of getting this arrangement and multiplied by 3.. is that right? thanks